# Neo4j and spring-data-neo4j - importing large datasets

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `Neo4j` database with `spring-data-neo4j`. Now, I want to import pretty large datasets so I looked into the capabilities of `neo4j` for batch insertions.

After my research I found out about:

1. `BatchInserter` for embedded database: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html and Michael Hunger project that uses it: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/
2. REST Batch endpoint: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html which allows to send multiple operations in single request (so multiple operations are executed in one transaction).

Now, I am wondering if it is possible to somehow use the repository feature of `spring-data-neo4j` for batch inserts, because even the method `save(Iterable<U> entities)` in `AbstractGraphRepository` just iterates through every element and invokes `save` for one entity:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public <U extends T> Iterable<U> save(Iterable<U> entities) {
    for (U entity : entities) {
        save(entity);
    }
    return entities;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no official support for batch insertion.

But you can try something like this: http://code.paananen.fi/2012/04/05/neo4j-batchinserter-and-spring-data-for-neo4j/

It is using SDN versions pre 3.0 though